# Image Rollovers Inside Facebook Tab Page

Tags: css, facebook, css-sprites

I'm trying to use a simple CSS-sprite for image-based rollovers inside a Facebook Tab page, and the background images are being stripped by Facebook. To be clear, this problem only occurs inside a **Tab** page, but not in the main application itself.

Facebook also appears to be extremely picky about when it strips background images - background images applied to **anchor tags** are removed, but background images applied to the **list element** containing the anchor remain intact.

For example, given the markup:

```
<li><a href="http://some/destination.html" target="_top"><img src="http://absolute/path/to/spacer-image.png" alt="" width="172" height="43" /></a></li>
```

the following CSS will apply a background to the list element successfully:

```
li {
    background: url(http://absolute/path/to/some/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

but the same CSS applied to the child anchor tag is stripped out by Facebook:

```
li a {
    background: url(http://absolute/path/to/some/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Is Facebook actually capable of supporting image-based rollovers inside a tab, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered a solution of sorts through trial and error, though it involves invalidly stacked html and looks pretty nasty.

Modify the markup so a div is **inside** the anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://some/destination.html" target="_top"><div><img src="http://absolute/path/to/spacer-image.png" alt="" width="172" height="43" /></div></a>
```

and apply the background image to the **div** instead of the anchor:

```
li a div {
   background: url(http://absolute/path/to/some/image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

You can then apply the background offset like this:

```
li a:hover div { background-position: 0 -43px; }
```

It does work but I'd much rather a less-hacky solution if anyone can suggest something.